# Regex For The Following IP Addresses

Tags: regex

I'd appreciate some help with this Regex which I don't seem to be able to resolve. I know it's simple, but obviously, I'm just not getting it.

It's a search for all IP addresses above: 32.0.0.0, in other words, all addresses from 32.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]|[3-9][0-9][3-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

Comment: Are you **sure** you can't chose another tool than regex to retrieve your IPs? Because it just sucks at this task.

Comment: I a doing a search for all IP addresses in a TFS repository which has thousands of files in it. Any suggestions for a better way?

Comment: Extract numbers in the `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` format with regex, then validate them with a tool that has a concept of IP

Comment: Well ctwheels provided a perfectly good answer anyway, so I might just be talking out of my ass. Don't put too much trust into the leading and trailing `\b` though, they don't guarantee much (e.g. there would be a match in `999.32.12.31.45.999`)

Comment: I am really not sure that regex is the right tool here, you may want to parse this doing number value comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/jXrqGr/2)

```
\b(?:0?3[2-9]|0?[4-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d{1,2})){3}\b
```

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?:0?3[2-9]|0?[4-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])` Match one of the following options

  - `0?3[2-9]` An optional `0`, followed by `3`, followed by a digit in the range of `2-9` (32-39)
  - `0?[4-9]\d` An optional `0`, followed by a digit in the range of `4-9`, then by any digit (40-99)
  - `1\d{2}` Match `1`, followed by any two digits (100-199)
  - `2[0-4]\d` Match `2`, followed by any digit in the range of `0-4`, then by any digit (200-249)
  - `25[0-5]` Match `25`, followed by a digit in the range of `0-5` (250-255)
- `(?:\.(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d{1,2})){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

  - `\.` Match a literal dot
  - `(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d{1,2})` Match one of the following options

    - `2[0-4]\d` Match `2`, followed by any digit in the range of `0-4`, then by any digit (200-249)
    - `25[0-5]` Match `25`, followed by a digit in the range of `0-5` (250-255)
    - `[01]?\d{1,2}` Matches an optional `0` or `1`, followed by any digit once or twice (0-199)
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Added explanation, sorry, took a little while